# Ansible jinja templating: variable number of group keys

Tags: shell, ansible, jinja2, ini

I'm writing a shell ansible script and one of the things I need to do is populate a list in an ini file from an inventory file using jinja2.

Currently it takes in variables component_group_1 and component_group_2 for group keys and populates a list of components from there

```
components: "{{groups[component_group_1]+groups[component_group_2]}}"
```

How can I rewrite this line so that it so that it can take just a single variable named all_component_groups, which has all the needed group keys in this pattern 'customers,vendors,products....', and where there can be any number of group keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to have your var as a list:

```yaml
all_component_groups_list:
  - group1
  - group2
  - group3
```

Meanwhile, it's quite easy to create a list from your pattern

```
all_components_groups: "customers,vendors,products"
all_components_groups_list: "{{ all_components_groups.split(',') }}"
```

Once you got that the rest is also quite easy:

1. extract the relevant lists from the `groups` dict with [`map` => `extract`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers)
2. `flatten` the list of lists to get a single one containing all values
3. use the `unique` filter to remove possible duplicated values

Putting it all together from your coma separated list requirement

```yaml
components: "{{ all_component_groups.split(',') | map('extract', groups) | flatten | unique }}"
```